# Is data left on disk in demand paging?

Tags: operating-system, paging

In demand paging, is the data copied from disk into main memory, or it is transferred into main memory, leaving nothing behind in the disk?

Comment: What do you imagine a "transfer" would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is "moved". Data is not a sheet of paper that can only be in one place at a time; it gets copied into memory, and afterwards it's still on disk. Erasing it on the disk would mean overwriting it with different data, which takes additional time after doing the read.

It may eventually get overwritten, since the system will, of course, know what parts of the swap are still valid and required data, and which parts are considered "unused".

Answer (score 0):

Actually none of the above. Traditionally, process and files have their contents copied into memory whenever they are requested. With demand paging, however, this is not the case. When a file is requested to be loaded into memory, the operating system marks a place for that file to be inside the virtual address space of the process, but does not actually allocate the memory or copy the file. As soon as the process reads or writes to that area of memory, the processor throws a fault which the operating system traps. The operating system then copies the contents of the file to the page *only* then. This has the effect of saving memory as only the pages which are actually accessed are allocated. This is also true for heap allocation. If a program requests a large block of memory, it actually isnt allocated until the program uses that memory.